# Проблемы с темой в yii2

Tags: yii2, gridview, themes

Поставил тему вот эту https://yii2.themefactory.net/theme/5/on-the-beach# . И перестала отображаться таблица GridView, данные есть, а поля пропали и никак не регулируются по нормальному. Вот так выглядит http://joxi.ru/VrwnejbHGXJ6AX .
Пробовал делать так, но не помогает:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'tableOptions' => [
        'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered',
        'style' => 'line-height: 20px',
    ],
```

line-height регулируется, но вот вернуть ей "стандартный" вид не получается. В css темы про таблицы ничего нет, вернее есть, но к этому не относится.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было добавить в layouts/main.php такие строки:
`$asset = frontend\assets\FrontendAsset::register($this);
$baseUrl = $asset->baseUrl;`
А так же во FrontendAsset.php:

```
public $css = [
    'themes/on-the-beach/files/main_style.css'
```

Теперь таблицы из GridView и DetailView отображаются.